# Using axios put with retrieving the auto increment identity value

Tags: sql-server, axios, auto-increment

The frontend client uses VUE.JS with axios to communicate with the C# .NetCore Backend. As database a Microsoft SQL Server is used. 
I try to achieve a axios put (for creating a new object in database) but the database is using an auto increment id column.
The frontend client do not have access to ALL data (per user security restrictions) and do not know the "latest id column".
We decided to use only Stored Procedures in our database and do not act with the tables directly. But this should not be relevant for my question.

I tried to change the backend code to return data (similar to working GET-Implementations). The specified Stored Procedure will return "SELECT @@IDENTITY". But the response does not contain any data (only Status code 200 and some HTTP Headers). And of course: the Stored procedure did create the object correctly!

The frontend code is simple:

```
return axios.put('addnewobject', {
        'QuestionText': questionText,
        'AnswerText': answerText,
      },
      { 
        baseURL: this.baseURL,
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        return response;
      });
```

The backend code looks like (tried to do it like GET HTTP requests):

```
       [HttpPut("addnewobject")]
        public async Task AddNewQA([FromBody] QandAModelObj qaObj)
        {
            try
            {
                Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", Common.JsonContentType);

                var cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC [REP].[QA_AddNewEntry] @QuestionText = @QuestionText, @AnswerText = @AnswerText");

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("QuestionText", qaObj.QuestionText);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("AnswerText", qaObj.AnswerText);

                await SqlPipe.Sql(cmd).Stream(Response.Body, "[]");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogError(ex, "AddNewQA failed");
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I want to do a put request with axios AND return the identity value (created in database) in response, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem.

Using

```
SqlPipe.Sql(cmd).Stream(Response.Body, "[]");
```

the Belgrade.SqlClient.IQueryPipe default implementation seems to force a JSON result. So I changed my StoredProcedure to return a JSON instead of the id only.

I am surprised that no warning and no error will occur, if the QueryPipe could not receive a propper JSON result. Instead of it it will create an empty response Body and status 200 :-/

After changing to propper JSON, axios will receive the response (here: my identity id) in body.